# Rails, Prawn PDF Gem - undefined method `table' for

Tags: pdf-generation, prawn, ruby-on-rails-4.1, ruby-2.1

Rails 4.1.1
Ruby 2.1.2

Gemfile : 
    gem 'prawn', '~> 2.0.0'

I have PDF's working ok. I am now trying to add table in the pdf. But when i add table I get the following error...

```
undefined method `table' for XPDFClass
```

I tried adding...

```
require "prawn/table"
```

to the top of my file but then i get this error...

```
cannot load such file -- prawn/table
```

Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `prawn-table` in your Gemfile, in addition to the `prawn` gem. That should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes I did try that. In my Gemfile I have "gem 'prawn-table'" directly under the prawn gem. I then add the require 'prawn/table' to top of my file, but I still get "undefined method `table' for XPdf:Class"

Answer (score 0):

It was my own fault, I had table outside of a method. Working version...

```
def table_rows
  table([
    ["X", "Y"]
  ])
end
```

When it wasn't working I had it as just...

```
table([
  ["X", "Y"]
])
```